# Why does it take up to 30 minutes to import medium size data set into R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown

I'm working on a report and I'm using R Markdown. I have a 1.5 GB dataset which takes no time, around 20 sec, to import into R but when importing the dataset into R when using R Markdown it takes around 15 minutes.

I'm using read_csv.

Is this normal, should I use other function than read_csv?

Comment: `readr::read_csv()` is faster than `read.csv()` but slower than some of the other fast-reading functions, see: https://appsilondatascience.com/blog/rstats/2017/04/11/fast-data-load.html. If you're concerned, try one of those. That said, I would guess the issue is an unintentional `print()` statement or something rather than the load per se.

Comment: Thank you so much. The trick was to use read_feather instead of read_csv.